# Is it good practice for MVVM data models to contain methods?

Tags: xamarin, mvvm

I am trying to use the MVVM architecture to develop a To-Do list app. A ToDoItem is stored in a JSON file and contains various properties (e.g. Title, Description, and Difficulty). The app assigns a Difficulty to the ToDoItem based on input parameters from the user and other properties of the ToDoItem.

Should the method which calculates the Difficulty be part of the ToDoItem model? If not, would it be better in the ToDoItemViewModel or in another class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly ok for model classes to expose methods that are specific to the domain model they are representing. Consider the following case:

```
class Car
{
    public double Fuel { get; private set; }

    public void AddFuel(double amount)
    {
        //todo
    }
}
```

It is perfectly fine for such a class to expose that method, within wich you can perform all sort of validations (that the tank is not already full, etc).

On thing that you should not expose (in most cases) in a model class is data persistence, which does not belong to the domain that is being represented by the model.

Another thing to consider is **Inmutability**, which is in general always a good thing. I would say that for a `ToDoItem` does not make sense to expose a way to change its `Difficulty`, so this should be a `readonly` property, therefore it should be injected in the constructor IMO

Consider then the semantic dimension of your implementation, for a `Car` it makes sense to have a way to change the amount of `Fuel` it has, ask yourself: Does it makes sense for a TodoItem to change its difficulty after having been created?